# How to loop this Group by json value in *ngFor in angular 9?

Tags: angular

```
{
    "ABC 111": [
        {
            "id": 01,
            "valueOne": 50,
            "valueTwo": "string",
            "valuethree": "string"
        },
        {
            "id": 02,
            "valueOne": 50,
            "valueTwo": "string",
            "valuethree": "string"
        }
    ],
    "XYZ 222": [
        {
            "id": 01,
            "valueOne": 50,
            "valueTwo": "string",
            "valuethree": "string"
        },
        {
            "id": 02,
            "valueOne": 50,
            "valueTwo": "string",
            "valuethree": "string"
        }
    ]

}
```

The error is :
Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Comment: you need to iterate over the variable `TN 47 RG 7845` as that is the array, instead of an object.

Comment: The variable is keep on changing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to change anything in **.ts** file. Change only inside the **html**.

Assume you have **responseObj** .

```
  <div *ngFor="let obj of responseObj | keyvalue">
        <div *ngFor="let item of obj.value">
            {{item.id}}
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: How to bind the values "ABC 111" and "XYZ 222" in above json ?

Comment: use obj.key to bind the value

Answer (score 1):

[image]i solved this prob on this url

[code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-playground-2jqqgu)

[appUrl](https://angular-playground-2jqqgu.stackblitz.io)

please check

```
<div *ngFor="let obj of  tesObj ">
        <div *ngFor="let item of obj">
          {{item|json}}
        </div>
</div>
```

it ts File

```
tesObj=Array.from(Object['values'](this.originalObj))
```